# Shared services between react and angular

Tags: javascript, angular, reactjs

At my company, we have 3 apps, 1 ng8, 1 vue and a new one in react.

I am looking for a way to write a shared core library to put our common services there (login, auth, storage, etc), services that are common and are not related to the DOM (mostly HTTP calls to our API's).

Its currently written in angular and enjoys that built-in DI, as they use each other.

The idea is to write it in vanilla javascript to allow all frameworks to use it.

**Updated:**

**Current simplified angular impl:**

```
//file: auth.service.ts:
export class AuthService {

    setCred(uname: string, token: string) {

    }

    getCred() {

    }
}


//file: login.service.ts:

import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

export class LoginService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient, private authService: AuthService) {

    }

    login(email: string, pass: string): Observable {
        return this.http.post('/login', {email, pass}).subscribe(response => {
            this.authService.setCred(response.uname, response.token);
        }
    }
}
}
```

**I want to be able to use both services in the angular app like this:**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FeatureService {

  constructor(
    private httpClient: HttpClient,
    private authService: AuthService,
    private userService: UserService
  ) {

    console.log('feature service init', authService.getCred());
  }
}
```

Is there a known method for this kind of requirement?

I would still want to facilitate DI in the library.

How would I consume such services in angular?

do I need to wrap them in an Angular service?

Comment: create node modules of javascript core packages like axios.

Answer (score 1):

I would move all your API calls into modules that can be imported in your React, Vue and Angular Apps. You can use `fetch` or one of the many other `HttpClient` modules out there on NPM.

From the Angular side of things, there's a con to doing this. Angular wants you to use the `HttpClient` module so if you ditch that and go with your shared module, you're going to lose a lot of those features. So, if you need the `HttpInterceptor` setup, you'll have to create your own instead of using Angulars since you're not using their `HttpClient`. I haven't worked with React or Vue enough to know if they also have their own `HttpClient` modules.

Example of what a basic service might look like using `fetch`

```js
class TodoService {
  constructor() {}
  static getTodo(id) {
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
      fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${id}`).then(r => resolve( r.json() ) );
    });
  }
  // ...
}

TodoService.getTodo(1).then(t => console.log(t) );
```

Once you figure out what your want in your module, then you can `export` the service and then `import` it wherever you need to. Keep in mind, if you introduce dependencies into the module, you'll have to package up the module so that your dependencies ship with the module.

Comment: I assumed this solution, but how will that behave with angular DI? and what about DI in my library? I have updated the question to include sample code.

Comment: The above example would work with DI no problem. If you end up needing it to be injectable you can always add the `@Injectable` decorator and setup your custom `provider` within your `ngModule`. Afer that, it'd be ready to go.

Comment: ... keep in mind though, you're trying to make this used by all, so if you start throwing in `@Injectable` on your service, you have now made Angular a dependency. Which is a lot for something that should be able to be used by anyone/anything.

Comment: You might want to look into Swagger / OpenApi. You can generate clients directly from your Api Code. That way, anyone can take your `swagger` file and generate a client that uses Angular, Fetch and something else. It's a slightly different approach to having a shared service that can be consumed by all. It's pushing the commonality to the server instead of creating a wrapper.

Answer (score -1):

In this case your services should be framework/libs agnostic. This about it as if it was another layer that are split into domains as you've described. A repository might be created to store this project and. Those apps can install it using NPM.